# Starting points for restoring drag'n'drop functionality in archivers

Tags: gnome, xorg

I recently updated my Ubuntu to 22.10 and lost the drag'n'drop functionality in archivers.

I'd like to get into the code and try to fix it by myself.

Here's my understanding of the problem so far:

- Achivers Drag'n'drop is not working with Wayland for security reasons. Fixing the issue for Wayland looks more like a design & security problem. I don't want to go that way and will only try to fix it for Xorg / Gnome.
- Archivers Drag'n'drop was working with Gnome 3.xx, but the switch to Gnome 4 in recent Ubuntus (22.10) broke that support.
- The problem could be fixed in file-roller's code by "just" adapting some API calls (no need to change anything at a lower-level).

The latest point above might sound very naive :)

My plan is to identify where the drag'n'drop is handled in file-roller, check the API differences between Gnome 3.xx and Gnome 4, guess what could be the breaking change and hopefully fix it. Again, I might be very naive here.

If anybody here has any hints or entry points for that task, that would be warmly welcome :) It could also be that some of my assumptions above are wrong. Let me know if that's the case.